# merging checkbox selection into appendChild

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently creating a Checkbox and trying to append the selections to a function.

This is what I currently have :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="Animal" value="Animal" name="langs" checked><label for="UW">UW</label><br>

<input type="checkbox" id="Vegatable" value="Vegetable" name="langs"><label for="OIB">OIB</label><br>

<input type="text" id="Other" value="N/A" name="langs" style="font-size:10px;" style="width: 125px;" /><label for="Other">Other</label><br>
```

This is what I currently have for the Appendchild Result:

```
<tr name="checkbox_value"><th>Systems Used: </th>
        </tr>
```

I'm using the option Document.getElementId but I can't get multiple result or a single result

```
 var SysRow = document.getElementById("checkbox_value");


var td4 = document.createElement("td");


td4.innerHTML = document.getElementById("langs").value;


SysRow.appendChild(td4);
```

from my understanding i can use document.getElementsByClassName() or document.querySelectorAll() but I'm not sure how to implement it .

What if the person selects multiple results like "Animal" and "Vegetable".

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hamster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately.

Comment: sorry but i really don't get your question...what do you want do achieve?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I'm trying to create multiple boxes and if the person select multiple options , those options get combine. I'm using document.getElementbyId to get the results for some things . But from my understanding it doesn't work if you are using multiple check box selection. I'm looking for a way to get around specially if the user selects multiple options.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```js
var items=document.getElementsByClassName('appendInput');
var checkedItems ="";
for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
    if(items[i].type=='checkbox' && items[i].checked)
        checkedItems+=items[i].value+" ";
}
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = checkedItems;
```

```html
<input class="appendInput" type="checkbox" name="langs" value="Animal" checked>
<input class="appendInput" type="checkbox" name="langs" value="Vegetable" checked>
<input class="appendInput" type="checkbox" name="langs" value="N/A">

<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class on the elements that you want to append

```
<input class="toappend" type="text" name="element_1">
<input class="toappend" type="text" name="element_2">
<input class="toappend" type="text" name="element_3">
```

Then in JS

```
var allElements = document.querySelectorAll('.toappend');
```

allElements will become nodeList then you can pass it in the function

```
function yourFunction(elements) {

    // If you want to use forEach method, you have to convert the nodeList to an Array
    //ES5
    var arrElements = Array.prototype.slice.call(elements);  

    //ES6
    let arrElements = Array.from(elements);

    arrElements.forEach(function(currentEl, index, array) {
        var appendTo = document.querySelector('#checkbox_value');
        appendTo.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', currentEl.outerHTML);
    });

}
```

Check this [pen](https://codepen.io/gadawag/pen/dwXOaZ)

Comment: could you please append those values in your `//do something` block? this would answer the question and is worth an upvote

Comment: Hello, i have edited my answer. please give it a try.